# Decompose a OpenERP lambda

Tags: python, lambda, odoo

In my OpenERP application, I have a lambda that I am trying to understand (currency_id):

```
_defaults = {
       'display_type': True,
       'journal_ids': [],
       'target_move': False,
       'currency_id': lambda self, cr, uid, c: self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, c).company_id.currency_id.id,
   }
```

So far, I understand it is doing this:

- start with table **res_users**, which has a **company_id** field
- uses the **browse** command to access a connected record

The **browse** function has the prototype of: **browse**(cr, uid, ids, context=None). We are passing it the **uid** as the **ids**. **Why are we passing the uid instead of ids?**

The **res_company** table has the **currency_id** field.

Then I assume it is using the foreign keys to access it via OpenERP's ORM. **How does the ORM know how to connect to the **res_company** field?**

Similar question
[what is the reason of using _defaults and lambda in python for openerp development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293630/what-is-the-reason-of-using-defaults-and-lambda-in-python-for-openerp-developme/19294524#19294524)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: we do want to pass ids to `browse`. However, in this case `uid` is the id of the `res.users` object who is *currently logged in*. Thus,

`self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, c)`

returns the `browse_record` object corresponding to the *logged in user*. This user has a company associated with it (via `company_id`) which has a currency (`currency_id`), and we use that currency's id as the default currency for anything this user does.